# How to call php function which is inside a class (external file) from jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

in my php script at the top i have `require_once('../registration/include/membersite_config.php');` wich is a class with all my site functions. This class is called *fgmembersite*. There is a function inside that i normaly call with *$fgmembersite->stats* but now i have to call it from a jquery function.

In the same php script i have this jquery code:

```
$('a.slick-toggle').click(function(){
      var the_id = $(this).attr('href');
      var div_id = $('#job_' + the_id);
      if ($(div_id).is(":visible")==false) {
      //Here i will put the AJAX CALL
      }
      $(div_id).toggle(400);
      return false;
    });
```

I want to call the *stats()* function form the jquery code when my condition is trigered, but this function is inside a class wich is already loaded with the requiere_once from the top.

Normaly when i make an ajax call i pass the parameters via POST to a function writen in other php file using for example: `$.ajax({ url: 'addremovelive.php', data: {addname: val,addlevel: val1}, type: 'post',success: function(d) {$('#add_lang_level').val('');$('#add_lang').val('');}});`

Using that method means that i will have to change my struture in the class in order to respond to a post call. There is another method to call my function using jquery/ajax?

Thanks for any orientation!

Comment: You cannot call any PHP method from jQuery/Ajax directly.

Comment: I have not came across direct method calling from jquery. For purposes like this i always make one file usually ajax.php that handles all business of calling everything and returning everything.

Comment: @arma - there is no "method" for direct calling of [insert language] method from within javascript. Data exchange doesn't happen directly, there's always proxy in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call methods/functions or anything from jquery directly.
But what you can do is trigger only the required method with a post/get variable from jquery. Means you have to add as you did before a post call to the file with the functions and yes - change the method so that it gets triggered as soon as a certain post/get variable is included in the call.